# R ifelse more than command in the true section/ ifelse Returns False when it is actually TRUE

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am new to R. I've looked for an answer to my question, but failed to find anything that works for me.

I have the following data.table:

```
data2 <- fread("file.txt", header = T, sep= "|", quote = "^" stringsAsFactors=FALSE);

Accounts_filed_date Incorporation_Date 
         2015-08-25         1863-05-01   
         2016-06-28         1863-07-16    
         2016-06-29         1863-12-29  
         2015-12-10         1880-08-17

Y <- function(incorporation_date, accounts_filled_date)
{timee <-Sys.Date()-incorporation_date;timee <- as.numeric(timee);
  if(timee/365 <2){y=0; return(y)}
  else{x <- as.Date(format(accounts_filled_date, "%2016-%m-%d"));
   + x <- Sys.Date()- x;
   + x <- as.numeric(x);
   + if(x<274) {y <-timee/365; return(pmax(pmin(y,5),0))}
   + else{y<-timee/365-1; return(pmax(pmin(y,5),0))}}}

data2[, c("Y") := Y(Incorporation_Date, Accounts_filed_date), with = FALSE]
```

However, that doesn't work because incorporation_date and accounts_filled_date are vectors.

I've tried ifelse but with the following code:

```
Y <- function(incorporation_date, accounts_filled_date) 
{timee <- Sys.Date()-incorporation_date;timee <- as.numeric(timee); 
timee<- timee/365;
ifelse(timee<2,y=0,
       x<-as.Date(format(accounts_filled_date, "%2016-%m-%d"));
       x <-Sys.Date()- x;
       x <- as.numeric(x);
       ifelse(x<274,y <-timee, y<- timee-1));
return(pmax(pmin(y,5),0))}
```

which returns the following:

```
Error: unexpected ';' in "Y <- function(incorporation_date, accounts_filled_date) {timee <- Sys.Date()-incorporation_date;timee <- as.numeric(timee); timee <- timee/365;ifelse(timee<2,y=0,x
```

Basically, my question is:
How can I include more than one action in the 'false' part of the ifelse statement?

**UPDATE**

```
Y <- function(incorporation_date, accounts_filled_date) 
 {timee <- Sys.Date()-incorporation_date;timee <- as.numeric(timee); 
 timee2<- timee/365;
 timee2 <- as.integer(timee2);
 x<-as.Date(format(accounts_filled_date, "%2016-%m-%d"));
   x <- Sys.Date()- x;
   x <- as.numeric(x);
ifelse**(timee2 <= 2,** y<-0, ifelse(x<274,y <-timee2, y<- timee2-1));
 return(pmax(pmin(y,100),0))}
```

This works, except for the time<=2, bit. I've double checked - it returns values less than two, just the logical returns FALSE. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using semicolons (;) and pluses (+)? These are rarely (if ever) necessary in base R.

Comment: Isn't this the only way to execute more than one action? +s are caused by saving some of the code in .txt document.

Comment: In instances where that is necessary, wrapping the code block in `{}` is a good way to go. However, it looks to me like your coding logic needs to be reworked. First, create x regardless of your condition (`timee<2`). This should greatly simplify your problem. Second, using assignment inside of `ifelse` is odd and probably unecessary: `ifelse(x<274,y <-timee, y<- timee-1)` should look more like `y <-  ifelse(x<274, timee, timee-1))` and could even be `y <- timee - (x<274)` which would be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-arranging the statement captures the logical:

```
Y <- function(incorporation_date, accounts_filed_date) 
 {timee <- Sys.Date()-incorporation_date;timee <- as.numeric(timee); 
  timee2<- timee/365;
   x<-as.Date(format(accounts_filed_date, "%2016-%m-%d"));
   x <- Sys.Date()- x;
   x <- as.numeric(x);
   y <- ifelse(timee2 <= 2, 0,ifelse(x < 274, timee2, timee2-1));
   return(pmax(pmin(y,5),0))}
```